# how to set flexible top & bottom constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

I have a view1 on top of the screen and another one view2 on bottom of the screen.

I have set the view1's top constraint as 25 and view2's bottom constraint as 25 .

I want both of the view's top and bottom to change between 10 to 25 and with the same ratio based screen availability.

i.e if view 1's top becomes 15 and view 2's bottom has to become 15

I tried setting greater than and less than for this constraints but its not working.

Any ideas on how to do this

update:

Basically there are some 3 to 4 labels and view1 on top and view2 on bottom.

3 to 4 labels are auto sizeable.

view1's top and view2's bottom I want to be flexible.

I tried to set less than 100 for top with priority 1000 and greater than 5 with priority 999 but Xcode throws error like the constraint is not equated. so I added top constraint 30 with priority 998.

the problem is top is always 30 now.

the same goes for view 2 as well.

Hope you understand my problem

Comment: Are you using storyboards or code to set up your constraints? Please share code or screenshots.

Comment: How are you setting the first views top to 15?

Comment: I am using storyboard

Comment: I am using top constraint

Comment: `V:|[top][bottom(==top)|`

Comment: can you please explain with words ?

Comment: You need to explain (or show) what you're trying to do. Do your views have a fixed height? Do you have a fixed vertical space between them?

Comment: @RajanM: we cannot help you if you don't provide **all information**. Please share screenshots of your constraints in your storyboard

Comment: I have updated my question with more relevant details

Comment: @RajanM - please add a screen-cap of what you are trying to layout. Your edited question is still unclear - you have 2 views, each with 3 or 4 labels, and the labels can be multiple lines? Or you have 3 or 4 labels, which can be multiple lines, and *then* you have 2 views? Or only one view has labels as subviews? Or something else? Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask